# load and read property file from struts.xml

Tags: java, struts2, struts-config

I am creating a project using Struts2.

I am setting the `global-results` tag in struts.xml in the following way:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="LOGIN" type="redirect">https://www.example.com</result>
</global-results>
```

I want to know if I can read the url from any other property file, so that if in future, the url gets changed, I only have to change in the property file. If I can, then how can I achieve this? Is there something like `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class of spring framework in struts2?

Comment: `struts.xml` is your configuration. Why use  a configuration to configure a configuration?

Comment: What difference does it make? Basically `struts.xml` is just *any other property file*.

Comment: I have to maintain three versions of code in the repository because of this url. If I can read the url from a property file, then I only have to maintain one copy of the project . It is basically for testing purposes in different environment.

Comment: Aren't you *maintaining* property files also?

Comment: Why do you think Struts configuration can use properties files as a placeholder for variables in `struts.xml`?

Comment: Thank you all for replying.I have 3 copies of the entire projects. I want to maintain only one copy. If I manage to change the link in the global tag by reading from some properties files, I think I can achieve that. If I can not do that, Please tell me if there is any other way at all?

Comment: It would be really helpful If I can get a definite answer on this. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe better to copy three versions of `struts.xml` and put them in three folders, named separately for dev, test and produc.... so it becomes some copy-paste work...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to achieve this: with Struts alone you cannot read properties name-value pair, but via Spring and action class you can.

With Spring `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` we can read value from `.properties` files with `${name.in.prop.file}`, so we can add parameters when constructing `Action` bean, like this:

```
<bean id="someAction" class="path.to.someAction" scope="session">
    <property name="manager1" ref="manager1" />
    <property name="manager2" ref="manager2" />
    <property name="myWebsiteURL" value="${my.website.url}" />
</bean>
```

And, define this `myWebsiteURL` of type `java.lang.String` in Action class, along with its getter/setter, so Spring can inject the value you need in `myWebsiteURL` upon Action class's creation.

At last, invoke this value like this in `struts.xml` with `${myWebsiteURL}`(the reason why it's working is still to be investigated, but it's working). For example, you can write this:

```
<action name="goToSomeSite" method="goToSomeSite" class="myAction">
     <result name="success" type="redirect">${myWebsiteURL}</result>
     ....
</action>
```

The only thing that I don't understand, is how `${myWebsiteURL}` is get evaluated. With Spring? Struts? JSTL? (I don't include JSTL libs in my project)